# First letter based filter search

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The problem is I want to filter the word in my list in first letter first format.

as you can see now I type the letter "**a**" in my search field, the result is all "**a**" related words. But I want the "**a**" first letter words only.

Then I type "**an**" the result should be "**an**" starting words.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agitha</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)` should be changed to

```
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === 0)
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === 0) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agitha</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startsWith()` instead of `indexOf()`

in you JS replace `if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)`

with `if (txtValue.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter))`

read more about [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Phonebook</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agitha</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  </ul>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startsWith()` function to get the results.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Phonebook</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agitha</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  </ul>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead.

```
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    let filterLength = filter.length;
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.substr(0, filterLength).toUpperCase() === filter) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 // this function will help you to filter array on the basis of first // letter or word
const collections = ["Ali","Ali and Asif", "Umar OR usman"];
const searchByMultipleWords = (
  collections,
  value
) => {
  return collections.filter((collection) => {
    const collectionName = collection
      ? collection.toLowerCase()
      : "";

    return collectionName.startsWith(value.toLowerCase());
  });
};
console.log(searchByMultipleWords(collections,"ali"))
```